# impact on performance with high usage of static variables in javascript and react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, static, static-variables

we have an mobile application, built on react native. when i saw the code, there were lots and lots of static variables & methods. 
ex: string constants, some classes with static methods which are to be used across the app etc.

```js
class StringConstatnts {
  static myVar1 = "var1";
  static myVar2 = "var2";
}
```

another

```js
class GlobalMethods {
  static _globalObj = {
    count: 0,
    obj: {}
  }

  static add() {
    ...
  }

  static remove() {
    ....
  }
}
```

likewise if we are heavily using static objects, will effect performance of the app? Can someone share some info on it?

Comment: Use where it is appropriate. If you mark it as static, it is added to `GlobalMethods.add` else it goes to `GlobalMethods.prototype.add`. If you want to use the class instance `this` inside the method, make it non-static. If it has nothing to do with the instance and a standalone pure function that does some task that you want to call `GlobalMethods.add()`, then  make it static.

Comment: @adiga i understand the usage of static & instance variables. my question is about, how it will impact the performance. having more static properties, variables, methods will it slodown? increase the dynamic memory?